# Project Server 2013 File Save Without Prompt

Tags: vba, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013

I’m trying to save a file that I previously opened on Project Server 2013. The only updates I’ve made to the files is to set the status date and move unfinished tasks. I’m running the file in excel VBA. I can share the complete set of code but I do not think it is necessary. If I run the macro without saving the files everything runs perfectly. All I need to do is get the files to save without prompting me and I’m done. All help is appreciated.

```
Dim appPJ As MSProject.application

Set appPJ = New MSProject.application

appPJ.FileOpenEx Name:="<>\" & strFileName, ReadOnly:=False, Noauto:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, DoNotLoadFromEnterprise:=False

'Update the status date and move unfinished tasks to the future

appPJ.ProjectSummaryInfo StatusDate:=dateStatusDate

appPJ.UpdateProject All:=True, UpdateDate:=dateStatusDate, Action:=2

'Call the various read data only report routines

appPJ.DisplayAlerts = False

appPJ.FileCloseEx pjSave, True, True
```

The line above will not save to server with a prompt.

Comment: I have found a clue to the problem. It appears that all of the files are opening as read only. The syntax of the fileopenex (above) say readonly false but when I look up the file type it is “pjProjectTypeEnterpriseReadOnly.” Does anyone know how to open a MS Project 2013 server file in read/write mode?